# Cant find the tag library "http://richfaces.org/a4j" n "http://richfaces.org/rich"

Tags: jsp, richfaces, primefaces-extensions

Hello im trying to import these 2 rich faces libraries into my .jsp file but it seems to be unreachable.

Ive google it and it seems to be uncompatible with jsp but id like to find a wat to make it compatible, any idea?

Comment: How exactly are you importing them?

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>

Comment: And you've added the library files to your project? You need RichFaces 3, RichFaces 4 does not work with JSP.

Comment: I see, i think im using last richfaces version, i guess i have to use and older version then?

Comment: Yes, as Makhiel said current RichFaces 4 version does not work with JSP. You can download RichFaces 3 from [here](http://richfaces.jboss.org/download/stable).

Comment: thnks alot it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

just summarize @makhiel and @lorenzo-gamboa and @vasil-lukach conversation:

1. jsp + richfaces 3 works together fine;
2. jsp + richfaces 4 not compatible;
3. you can find the tag library “http://richfaces.org/a4j” n “http://richfaces.org/rich” if you will use [resourse](http://richfaces.jboss.org/download/stable).

sorry, but this is 3rd conversation which contain solution in comments, better to find it in answers.